# Accessing English language reviews of iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, itunes

I'm on the creator side of iPhone apps so I'd like to read some of the reviews for our apps. However, because I'm German and don't have a US bank account, iTunes only shows me the German reviews. How can I see the US ones too? Trying to switch the account in my iTunes, Apple warns me that I need a US bank account, and that I have ongoing TV series subscriptions that can't be cancelled yet... and only offers a Cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official web-frontend for the AppStore can be accessed via http://itunes.apple.com/us but it shows only 3 reviews per app.
Another possibility is http://app-store.appspot.com
There you will find a few more reviews and I think they are also pulled from the US-store.